# Rotation using GStreamer/OpenCV without major latency increase (Jetson Nano, OpenCV 4.1, GStreamer 1.0, Python)

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson

I am currently running a program in Python to display video from a RPi Camera Module V2 on the Jetson Nano. I am using OpenCV4.1 and GStreamer 1.0. I understand that rotating the image can be done with both gstreamer and opencv, as done below:

OpenCV:

```
def rotate_image(img, angle=0):
    w = 1280
    h = 720
    center = (w / 2, h / 2)
    matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
    rotated_img = cv2.warpAffine(img, matrix, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return rotated_img
# This has been tested as both a Mat (using CPU) and as a UMat (with OpenCL ==> using GPU)
```

GStreamer Pipeline:

```
pipeline = 'nvarguscamerasrc ! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),width=1280, height=720, framerate=30/1, format=NV12 ! nvvidconv flip-method=0 ! video/x-raw,width={}, height={},format=BGRx ! rotate angle=0.78 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink '
# The key is "! rotate angle 0.78 !". rotate is a 'bad' gstreamer plugin
```

Both of these methods are entirely functional for rotating the video, but the issue is that both methods add significant latency whether done with the gstreamer rotate plugin, an OpenCV Mat, or an OpenCV UMat. Could anyone tell me if there is any way to rotate the video stream (or each individual frame) with less latency? Thanks

Comment: If you just want to display the rotated image, then you can use [OpenGL (ES)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/) or [Vulkan](https://www.khronos.org/vulkan/) and rotate the image in a shader program on the GPU.